# R: How to do group sorting based on attribute values (dates) row by row?

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a problem which I hope someone can help me with. It is basically data manipulation. I have a big dataset that consists of 10 columns, "id" and 3 sets of similar variables, "type","startdate", and "enddate". An example can be seen below.

```
  id type1 startdate1   enddate1 type2 startdate2   enddate2 type3 startdate3
1  1     A 2006-08-20 2006-12-06     W 2006-08-01 2007-08-29     P 2007-08-18
2  2     A 2006-01-05 2007-07-02    NA         NA         NA     Q 2008-01-15

    enddate3
1 2007-09-27
2 2008-02-07
```

I would like to obtain the following cleaned and sorted dataset:

```
  id type1 startdate1   enddate1 type2 startdate2   enddate2 type3 startdate3
1  1     W 2006-08-01 2007-08-29     A 2006-08-20 2006-12-06     P 2007-08-18
2  2     A 2006-01-05 2007-07-02     Q 2008-01-15 2008-02-07    NA         NA 

enddate3
1 2007-09-27
2 NA
```

I would like to sort in ascending order, every row/observation according to the "startdate". Hence for row 1, since the second group or set of variables has an earlier "startdate" (2006-08-01) as compared to the first group's "startdate" (2006-08-20), I would place it to the first position.

As for row 2, I would like to push all the NAs to the end.

Any tips on how I can do this efficiently?

Should I convert data type of "startdate" and "enddate" to numeric? If I should, how should I handle "NA"?

Is it wise to apply paste() function on the (type,startdate,enddate) for all the 3 sets?

Appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr` that relies on converting the dataset into long format, reordering as desired, and then converting back to wide format. The conversion to long format coerces values to `character`, so column types need to be reapplied.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id type1 startdate1   enddate1 type2 startdate2   enddate2 type3 startdate3   enddate3
 1     A 2006-08-20 2006-12-06     W 2006-08-01 2007-08-29     P 2007-08-18 2007-09-27
 2     A 2006-01-05 2007-07-02    NA         NA         NA     Q 2008-01-15 2008-02-07
")

df %>%
    gather(key, value, -id) %>%  # convert to long format
    extract(key, c("var", "seq"), "(.*)(\\d)") %>%  # extract sequence number
    spread(var, value) %>%  # spread to wide format by id and sequence
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(startdate) %>%  # sort seq by startdate in id groups
    mutate(seq = 1:n()) %>%  # calculate new sequence order
    gather(key, value, -id, -seq) %>%  # convert to long format
    transmute(var = paste0(key, seq), value) %>%  # generate wide format names
    spread(var, value) %>%  # spread to back to wide format
    select(one_of(names(df))) %>%  # restore original column order
    mutate_each("as.Date", one_of(grep("date", names(df), value = TRUE)))
        # reapply date type to original date variables

#     Source: local data frame [2 x 10]
#     Groups: id [2]
#     
#          id type1 startdate1   enddate1 type2 startdate2   enddate2 type3 startdate3   enddate3
#       (int) (chr)     (date)     (date) (chr)     (date)     (date) (chr)     (date)     (date)
#     1     1     W 2006-08-01 2007-08-29     A 2006-08-20 2006-12-06     P 2007-08-18 2007-09-27
#     2     2     A 2006-01-05 2007-07-02     Q 2008-01-15 2008-02-07    NA       <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Same approach as Mikko Marttila but without using non-standard libraries:

```
> ## use vectors of class Date
> df[c(3,4,6,7,9,10)] <- lapply(df[c(3,4,6,7,9,10)], as.Date)

> ## reshape to long format
> df.1 <- reshape(df, idvar=1,
+                 varying=list(c(2,5,8), c(3,6,9), c(4,7,10)),
+                 v.names=c('type', 'startdate', 'enddate'),
+                 times=c(1,2,3), timevar='group', direction='long')
> df.1
#     id group type  startdate    enddate
# 1.1  1     1    A 2006-08-20 2006-12-06
# 2.1  2     1    A 2006-01-05 2007-07-02
# 1.2  1     2    W 2006-08-01 2007-08-29
# 2.2  2     2 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 1.3  1     3    P 2007-08-18 2007-09-27
# 2.3  2     3    Q 2008-01-15 2008-02-07

> ## reset group variable according to startdate
> df.1$group <- with(df.1, unsplit(lapply(split(startdate, id), order), id))
> df.1
#     id group type  startdate    enddate
# 1.1  1     2    A 2006-08-20 2006-12-06
# 2.1  2     1    A 2006-01-05 2007-07-02
# 1.2  1     1    W 2006-08-01 2007-08-29
# 2.2  2     3 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 1.3  1     3    P 2007-08-18 2007-09-27
# 2.3  2     2    Q 2008-01-15 2008-02-07

> ## back to wide format
> df.2 <- reshape(df.1[order(df.1$group), ], idvar=1,
+                 v.names=c('type', 'startdate', 'enddate'), timevar='group',
+                 direction='wide')

> ## sort by id
> df.2 <- df.2[order(df.2$id), ]

> df.2
#     id type.1 startdate.1  enddate.1 type.2 startdate.2  enddate.2 type.3
# 1.2  1      W  2006-08-01 2007-08-29      A  2006-08-20 2006-12-06      P
# 2.1  2      A  2006-01-05 2007-07-02      Q  2008-01-15 2008-02-07   <NA>
#     startdate.3  enddate.3
# 1.2  2007-08-18 2007-09-27
# 2.1        <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package. Now, that function is intelligent enough to combine according to column names - we don't want that. To push the observations forward for each row, we remove NA's and then apply the names of the original data frame to the new vector.

```
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame("obs" = seq(3),
                 type1 = c(2,2,NA),date1 = c("date11","date21",NA), 
                 type2 = c(3,NA,5),date2 = c("date12",NA,"date31"),
                 type3 = c(4,3,1), date3 = c("date13","date22","date32"),
                 type4 = c(4,4,NA),date4 = c("date14","date23",NA))
df
#    obs type1  date1 type2  date2 type3  date3 type4  date4
#    1   1     2 date11     3 date12     4 date13     4 date14
#    2   2     2 date21    NA   <NA>     3 date22     4 date23
#    3   3    NA   <NA>     5 date31     1 date32    NA   <NA>

newdf <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
    newrow <- (df[i,!is.na(df[i,])])              ## Remove NA's
    names(newrow) <- names(df)[1:length(newrow)]  ## Apply names

    newrow                                        ## Output
})

rbind.fill(newdf)
#    obs type1  date1 type2  date2 type3  date3 type4  date4
#    1   1     2 date11     3 date12     4 date13     4 date14
#    2   2     2 date21     3 date22     4 date23    NA   <NA>
#    3   3     5 date31     1 date32    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
```

**Caution:** this code only works if `type` and the dates come together as either observed or NA's.

Comment: I *JUST* saw that you want the push to be dependent on the dates. I think essentially you are asking two questions - 1): how to push and 2): how to sort. I have only responded to the first question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems very useful as my dataset is very sparse, and I would really need to push the NAs to the right.